# cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser'

Tags: django

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

```
path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='example.html/')),
```

]

[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\CRM-DJANGO\:\example.html'

exact error is ='example.html'

want to open the example.html in django

Comment: Can you also show your `settings.py`?